# Colouring 3D columns defined by a piecewise function

Tags: plotting

I am using a piecewise function to define the height of columns. My goal is to make a nice picture that illustrates the different heights of the columns using color. Below in the picture I have described what I have generated using code on the left and on the right I have illustrated what I am trying to achieve:

[image]

Here is the code I used to generate the left picture:

```
pw = Piecewise[{{1, 0.1 <= x < 0.9 && 0.1 <= y <= 0.9}, {2, 
 1.1 <= x <= 1.9 && 0.1 <= y <= 0.9}, {1/2, 
 2.1 <= x <= 2.9 && 0.1 <= y <= 0.9}, {6, 
 3.1 <= x <= 3.9 && 0.1 <= y <= 0.9}, {0, True}}];

Plot3D[pw, {x, -0.01, 10}, {y, -0.01, 10}, MeshFunctions -> {#3 &}, 
MeshShading -> {Opacity[0.5, Red], Opacity[0.5, Green], 
Opacity[0.5, Orange]}, 
ExclusionsStyle -> {Opacity[0.1, Black], Opacity[1, Black]}, 
BoundaryStyle -> None]
```

Thanks for your time!

Comment: I would suggest using [``Histogram3D``](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Histogram3D.html) instead of ``Plot3D``. Easier to create nice and correct cuboids, and style them separately.

Comment: @Domen The styling provided by Histogram3D looks indeed as I need it! However, the data I want to use to create my plot comes from a piecewise defined function specifying height values, do you think this would be compatible with Histogram3D?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We can use `pw` to generate coordinates for `Cuboid`s and use them with `Graphics3D`:

```
pwToCuboidCoordinates = MapThread[Flatten /@ Thread[{Transpose@#, {0, #2}}] &, 
    Most /@ Internal`FromPiecewise[#] /. 
      And -> List /. 
       (LessEqual | Less | Greater | GreaterEqual | Inequality)[x__] :> 
         Sort[{x}[[{1, -1}]]]] &;

pw = Piecewise[{{1, 0.1 <= x < 0.9 && 0.1 <= y <= 0.9}, {2, 
     1.1 <= x <= 1.9 && 0.1 <= y <= 0.9}, {1/2, 
     2.1 <= x <= 2.9 && 0.1 <= y <= 0.9}, {6, 
     3.1 <= x <= 3.9 && 0.1 <= y <= 0.9}, {0, True}}];

cuboidCoordinates = pwToCuboidCoordinates[pw];

colors = ColorData["Rainbow"] /@ Rescale[cuboidCoordinates[[All, -1, -1]]];

Graphics3D[
 MapThread[{#, Cuboid @@ #2} &, {colors, cuboidCoordinates}], 
 PlotRange -> {{-.01, 10}, {-.01, 10}, All}, BoxRatios -> 1]
```

[image]

An alternative approach using `WeightedData` + `Histogram3D`:

```
wd = WeightedData @@ {Transpose[Map[Mean] /@ Transpose[#]], #2} & @@ 
   (Most /@ Internal`FromPiecewise[pw] /. 
     And -> List /. 
       (LessEqual | Less | Greater | GreaterEqual | Inequality)[x__] :> 
         Sort[{x}[[{1, -1}]]]);

Histogram3D[wd, {{-1, 10, 1}, {-1, 10, 1}}, 
 PlotRange -> {{-.01, 10}, {-.01, 10}, All}, BoxRatios -> 1, 
 ColorFunction -> "Rainbow", 
 ChartElementFunction -> "ProfileCube"]
```

[image]

Comment: These are awesome and clean solutions in both cases! For the first case, I noticed that when I place another cube behind the others it gets a different color, not based on height but based on position e.g. `pw = Piecewise[{{1, 0.1 <= x < 0.9 && 0.1 <= y <= 0.9}, {2, 
     1.1 <= x <= 1.9 && 0.1 <= y <= 0.9}, {1/2, 
     2.1 <= x <= 2.9 && 0.1 <= y <= 0.9}, {6, 
     3.1 <= x <= 3.9 && 0.1 <= y <= 0.9}, {10, 
     0.1 <= x <= 0.9 && 1.1 <= y <= 1.9}, {0, True}}];`

Is there anyway to adjust so the color is assigned based on height instead of position? Thanks!

Comment: @jcm, please see the updated version.

Answer (score 4):

Try this one

```
exp1 = ({{0.77, 0.04, 0.01, 0.0}, {0.04, 0.81, 0.0, 0.0}, {0.02, 0.0, 
    0.81, 0.08}, {0.0, 0.07, 0.04, 0.93}})
rest = exp1 - DiagonalMatrix[Diagonal[exp1]]; r = 
 Flatten[Table[n = Round[rest[[i, j]]*100]; 
   ConstantArray[{i, j}, n], {i, 4}, {j, 4}], 2]; d = 
 Table[n = Round[exp1[[i, i]]*100]; 
  ConstantArray[{i, i}, n], {i, 4}]; Histogram3D[
 Join[d, {r}], Automatic, "Probability", PlotRange -> All, 
 ChartLabels -> Placed[Diagonal[exp1], Above, "Framed"], 
 PlotTheme -> {"Marketing", "NoAxes"}]
```

[image]